# How to update view continuosly with ajax from webservice

Tags: ajax, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Using mvc, I have a controller that does a call to a webservice to fetch data and populate a grid every time I refresh the current page.

Is it possible to use ajax to make a call to this service, continuously, resulting in a live feed of data from the service?

This is how my view is setup:

```
@model FleetMonitorModel

<div class="span12">
    <legend>Fleet Monitor</legend>
        <div>
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<FleetMonitorModel>()
              .Name("Grid")
              .DataSource(ds => ds
                  .Ajax()
                  .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "FleetMonitor"))
              )
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:auto;" })
              .Columns(columns =>
                  {
                      columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(310);
                      columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(250);
                      columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(150);
                      columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ");
                      columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(80);
                  })
              .ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("_ClientRowTemplate", Model).ToHtmlString())
              .Pageable()
              .Sortable())
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my controller action:

```
private FleetMonitorModel Model { get; set; }

...

public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    UnitContract[] listOfUnitsFromService = Client.GetListOfUnits(true);

    Model = new FleetMonitorModel()
                {
                    UnitDetails = GenerateUnitDetails(listsOfUnitsFromService.ToList())
                };

    return Json(Model.UnitDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the Grid population method through javascript like  this:

```
var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');    
grid.dataSource.read();
```

After that you can call that method repeatedly to update the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I wanted to add the fact that we've successfully implemented SignalR with Kendo components, and it works perfectly :)